# Use JAXB and interpret same tag differently based on enclosing tag

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

In the below sample, the Data block inside A and the Data block inside B should be unmarshalled into different classes. Is this achievable using JAXB?

```
<Content>
  <A>
    <Data>
      <Name></Name>
      <Age></Age>
    </Data>
  </A>
  <B>
    <Data>
      <MobilePhone></MobilePhone>
      <WorkPhone></WorkPhone>
    </Data>
  </B>
</Content>
```

The Data inside A and the Data inside B represent different classes.The data inside A should be mapped to AData.class and the Data inside B should be mapped to BData.class.

Note: Marshalling is working fine. Any number of classes can have the same name tag. The generated xml contains the same tag for all those classes. In this case, AData and BData will both be written to XML as <Data> . But even the same marshalled xml cannot be unmarshalled again. I am hoping this can be solved by adding some additional annotations.

Comment: This simple recreation is working fine. But, my slightly-more-complex project code is not working.

Comment: Project code is also working fine :(  Logs were getting trimmed. I didnt check properly. JAXB is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have the following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {

    @XmlElement(name="Data")
    private AData data;

}
```

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class B {

    @XmlElement(name="Data")
    private BData data;

}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="Content")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Content {

    @XmlElement(name="A")
    private A a;

    @XmlElement(name="B")
    private B b;

}
```

Comment: I have to annotate classes AData and BData also using XmlRootElement right?

Comment: @Teddy - you only need to have the `@XmlRootElement` annotation on a class if you want to be able to unmarshal it as a top level object without having to specify a `Class` parameter:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution that Blaise has posted will be a good way to tackle this if you know ahead of time the objects that Content will contain, such as here:

```
public class Content {

    @XmlElement(name="A")
    private A a;

    @XmlElement(name="B")
    private B b;

}
```

But another way you could do this is to have the data that could be contained in content be wrapped in a list of some supertype that A/B extend from, which results in XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Content>
    <myContent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="a">
        <Data>
            <Name>Joe Smith</Name>
            <Age>25</Age>
        </Data>
    </myContent>
    <myContent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="b">
        <Data>
            <MobilePhone>555-234-5678</MobilePhone>
            <WorkPhone>555-555-5555</WorkPhone>
        </Data>
    </myContent>
</Content>
```

You can get this by annotating your classes like so:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Content")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Content {
    @XmlElement
    List<SomeSuperType> myContent;

    public Content() {

    }

    public List<SomeSuperType> getMyContent() { return this.myContent; }
    public void setMyContent(List<SomeSuperType> myContent ) { this.myContent = myContent; }
}

// class for A
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A extends SomeSuperType {
    @XmlElement(name="Data")
    AData data;

    public A() {
        data = new AData();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        data.name = name;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        data.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() { return data.name; }
    public int getAge() { return data.age; }
}

class AData {
    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "Age")
    int age;
}


// class for B
@XmlRootElement(name = "B")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class B extends SomeSuperType {
    @XmlElement(name = "Data")
    BData data;

    public B() {
        data = new BData();
    }

    public void setMobilePhone(String mobilePhone) { data.mobilePhone = mobilePhone; }
    public void setWorkPhone(String workPhone) { data.workPhone = workPhone; }
    public String getMobilePhone() { return data.mobilePhone; }
    public String getWorkPhone() { return data.workPhone; }
}

class BData {
    @XmlElement(name="MobilePhone")
    String mobilePhone;
    @XmlElement(name="WorkPhone")
    String workPhone;
    public BData() {

    }
}
```